# how to get the point coordinate in the screen with wxwidgets？

Tags: wxwidgets, coordinate

I want to get the point coordinate in the screen with wxwidgets. And control the mouse with wxwidgets. How can I start with it being a beginner of wxwidgets? I can only get some informations about [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxSmith_tutorial:_Drawing_on_the_Screen_and_Saving_Drawings), but I donot know how to use it!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For working with screen coordinates you should find [wxWindow::ScreenToClient()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a59d02b70a9107433836a977c4c0cd7a9) and its converse [ClientToScreen()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a7de852b144210b93b690189e99dbe1df) useful.

For controlling the mouse you have [WarpPointer()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ac500152d1eca3a2ee98a68e7ea7372b5).